# c# Json Post throws 404 bad request error

Tags: c#, json, post, request

I am new to JSON and C# and trying for a POST request and reading the response.

I am writing the Content Type correctly, url I am trying to send to the server is also correct. Probably my code is just incorrect and I will appreciate for any helps on this.

Below is my code but I keep getting 400 bad request.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Server
{
    public void ServerStart()
    {
        try{
            string webAddr="https://localhost:61000/users/login";

            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";    

            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{ \"userName\" : \"laborel\", \"userPassword\" : \"dGVzdG5ldFBDMSEu\" }";

                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
            }
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                byte[] responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(responseText);  
            }
        }catch(WebException ex){
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string.Format ("Exception Occurred: {0}",ex.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

One thing `byte[] responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();` is not right, where I am not sure what should bet the responseText

Could some one point me out on how can we create a function which accepts the webaddress and the json string as input and returns the response text

Comment: grab the inner message of `ex.Message` and print it to your log, it will tell you if its invalid json, or what the deal is. i will say if this is rest you probably need a header with an authorization token, but it could be a number of small things.

Comment: also it says 404 error in the question, which i believe is not found error, but error code 400 in the question body, which seems to be the correct error for bad request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following would work `string responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();`